# How can I allow Windows RDP ports with socat?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-8, arduino, socat

192.168.0.21 is a Windows 8.1 PC running RDP. Using Linux I am running [socat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) as below, but cannot connect on port 5900 to 3389. How do I make TCP and UDP traffic on 5900 go to 3389?

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5900,fork TCP:192.168.0.21:3389
```

Comment: RDP is TCP, so no need for UDP.  So rather than connect directly to 3389 on the target machine, you want to connect to 5900 on your local machine and have `socat` establish the 3389 connect?   What happens when you try to connect to localhost:5900?  What are you using to connect?

Comment: I use SOCAT in Arduino Linux which has 192.168.0.2 terminal access point. in that lan i have 192.168.0.21, 22, 23 with Windows 8.1 RDP. now Remotely i connect using RDP to the Linux port 5900 to access RDP. i get a black screen saying connecting....

Comment: Could you run socat with the `-dd` switch that you can confirm the connections are getting through.  The command is correct, so it s probably a connectivity issue.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pPrYZRS.png - please see screenshot. trying to connect but nothing happens.

Comment: On the arduino, could you try `telnet 192.168.0.21 3389` to confirm that it can connect to the Windows machine.  If it can, then is the OSX machine on the same network as the arduino?

Comment: Just to clarify, socat should eventually return a timeout if it cannot make the outgoing connection to the Windows machine and this will show up if you use `-dd`.  So it is probable that the OSX machine cannot connect to the arduino.

Comment: when i do `telnet 192.168.0.21 3389` i get no reply normally i should get reply `Connected to sun.
Escape character is '^]'.` right?

Comment: Yeah, that is right.  Are you able to RDP directly to the Windows machines from the 192.168.0.21 network?

Comment: NO - i had VNC installed later VNC failed since then i was trying RDP but i think RDP is not installed properly maybe that is the reason OSX now from remote location failing to reach it. So i think i have to go onsite thank you!!